# I am getting a no attribute error in my django rest api

Tags: python, django, django-models, serialization, django-rest-framework

models.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Question(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    content = models.TextField()
    # answers = models.ForeignKey(Answer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class Answer(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, related_name="comment_post", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    answer = models.CharField(max_length=750)
    date_answered = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question.title
```

serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from . import models

class AnswerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Answer
        fields = ('id', 'question', 'answer', )


class QuestionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    post_comment = AnswerSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = models.Question
        fields = ('id', 'title', 'post_comment', 'content', )
        depth = 1
```

I wanna view questions with all the answers they got but get the error :

AttributeError at /v1/question/
Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `post_comment` on serializer `QuestionSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `Question` instance.
Original exception text was: 'Question' object has no attribute 'post_comment'.

Comment: I can see you have defined Foreign key as `comment_post` instead of `post_comment` as specified in Serializer, are you sure you have correct field names across.

Comment: i added comment_post to serializer fields as you pointed out and it still is not working

Comment: Happy to help, Cheers buddy!!